# How to add period in postgresql, where period is available in year, month and days?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which is having following information :-

```
stateCode, empCode resedencyPeriod
10          2001     3Y5M20D
11          2002     5Y9M25D
12          2001     9Y9M20D
10          2001     9Y5M25D
11          2002     11Y11M22D
```

Where 3Y5M20D represents 3 Years 5 Months and 20 Days.
Now I want to know how long any employee stayed in a State. Desired output is as following

```
stateCode, empCode totalresedencyPeriod
10          2001     12Y11M15D
11          2002     17Y9M17D
12          2001     9Y9M20D
```

Is there any postgresql function to get desired output ?

Comment: Though this may be possible, you should be cautioned against using it as some months are longer than others.  Someone who has stayed in feb 01 to mar 01 will only have stayed 28 days where someone who has stayed may 01 to jun 01 will have stated 31.  This makes "months" a poor represention of time interval.  Adding them is very dangerous and misleading because it would only take 10 periods for that 3 day difference to become an entire month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `resedencyPeriod` to [interval type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-datetime.html) by prefixing the field with `P` letter:

```
select stateCode, empCode, ('P' || resedencyPeriod)::interval
from employee;

 statecode | empcode |         interval         
-----------+---------+--------------------------
        10 |    2001 | 3 years 5 mons 20 days
        11 |    2002 | 5 years 9 mons 25 days
        12 |    2001 | 9 years 9 mons 20 days
        10 |    2001 | 9 years 5 mons 25 days
        11 |    2002 | 11 years 11 mons 22 days
(5 rows)

select 
    stateCode, 
    empCode, 
    justify_days(sum(('P' || resedencyPeriod)::interval)) period
from employee
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;

 statecode | empcode |          period          
-----------+---------+--------------------------
        10 |    2001 | 12 years 11 mons 15 days
        11 |    2002 | 17 years 9 mons 17 days
        12 |    2001 | 9 years 9 mons 20 days
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @klin and @ couling for the solution and making me aware about he  the pros and cons of using this kind of approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is theoretically possible to do what you ask but **highly inadvisable**.  If yo want to do it anyway then here is how:

Postgresql has an `interval` data type which is very good at handling time periods.  It contains the ability to store days, months and years in one value and supports basic arithmatic.

It also contains a function `justify_days()` which assumes every month has 30 days.  This is okay as long as you know every month in your data was 30 days long.

---

As I indicate this is very dangerous...  You can't simply add days togeather to equal months because a month might have anything from 28 to 31 days and you are not recording which months are represented by a period.

You really should record this as a number of days (potentially in an `interval` type) or a start and end date in seperate fields.  Without this you will always end up with errors in your output.

Comment: There's nothing dangerous, if you understand how the summation of interval values acts. Justified sum of interval values may be flawed like any aggregated statistical data. Besides, you do not have to use `justify_days()` and operate on the exact number of days and months.

Comment: @klin Using months in this way breaks "Principle of least astonishment". The term "month" has a bunch of different meanings depending on context.  "Calendar month" and "30 days" are not the only two.  The point I make is that months should generally be avoided unless there is a very specific reason to keep them in. Otherwise the customer may raise a bug report when they see `3 years 13 months 96 days` or sue you when your software leads them to incorrectly file their tax returns. **No solution to this question can be thought of as a generic way to sum time intervals**

Comment: It is rather general discussion on *use interval or number of days?*. The author has chosen a sum of intervals and has got a proper solution with all props and cons. Are you going to say that the use of `round(val, 2)` is dangerous as `1.234 != 1.23`? It is a matter of aim.

Comment: @klin you've lost me completely there.  In the case of `round()` your intention is to drop precision. In the case of `sum()` it is an unintentional side effect which may be much larger than expected.  The OP has not stated the definition of a month and so both the OP and future readers **may not** spot the unintentional side effect.  Ergo... dangerous.

Comment: It is not *an unintentional side effect*. You can estimate the approximation error for both the sum of rounded numeric values as well as interval values.

Comment: I would rather say that this is an arithmetic property.

Comment: @klin You're dicing with words.  The fact remains that the OP has left the defanition of a month undefined.  Assumptions are dangeous. Not stating your assumptions is doubly dangerous.  This is an *arithmetic propery* which I've seen lead to many coding errors and that is why I continue to call it dangerous.